# Array only being updated on first iteration of a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

The following code takes an array of objects structured like so: {html:*whatever* number:*number value*}.

```
function Org(data){
//array of objects
var Data=data;
for(var i=0; i<Data.length; i++){
  var nums=[];
  nums.push(Data[i].number);
console.log(nums);}
}
```

Nums should have be logged to the console as [1,1] on the second iteration when called with: [{html:null,number:1},{html:null,number:1}] but instead is logged as [1] on both the first and second iterations. Why might this be?

Comment: Place var nums = [] outside of loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the initialization of `num` outside of the `for` loop. Inside it creates for each iteration a new empty array.

BTW, no need for using another variable for `data`.

```
function Org(data){
    var nums = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        nums.push(data[i].number);
    }
    console.log(nums);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or shorter:

```
var Org=data=>console.log(data.map(e=>e.number));
```